# Learning C# with exercises, questions and puzzles

Tags: c#

I learned Java with the help of the book 'Java how to program'. The book had lots of questions and exercises that helped me a lot.

I am now looking for a  website or preferably a book that has similar programming questions/exercises that will help me learn C#/.NET and become a better programmer. Could someone suggest a book or point me to a website ?

Thanks

Edit: I should add that I am not looking for advanced stuff like [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), but basic stuff

Comment: You could just hit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 and take a go at all the questions.

Comment: That, and reading through all the MSDN tutorials and guides on C#, of course. :P

Comment: I think your question is very constructive because I have the same problem after reading a book without exercises and documentations

Answer (score 10):

While it's specifically aimed at algorithmic programming, [**Project Euler**](http://projecteuler.net/) can only do good things for getting well-acquainted with a language! Work through as many problems as you can, solving them in C#, and you'll have fun at the same time as learning the language.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a bad site:

http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/csharp.shtml

Starts off with console applications doing "Hello World" and reading files and goes on to hit a long list of important concepts including database access using Parameters.

Answer (score 5):

The [Sphere online Judge](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/) has a good collection of programming problems, ranging from [tutorial](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/tutorial) problems to [challenge](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/challenge) problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you like working through exercises, solving puzzles, etc. while learning, you'll love the [Head First book on C#](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514822.do).

Answer (score 2):

APress Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform by Andrew Troelsen is the single best book I've read to quickly get into the language. It suggests concise relevant examples and code samples for the reader to try, and I recommend following them. It's a 1700 page book - very exhaustive and reasonably priced for the amount of content.