# Do you know any C# based "puzzles and answers" like book? Article? Resource?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, puzzle

Do you know any C# based "puzzles and answers" like book? Article? Resource?

Why I am asking this is to enlarge my vision with some interesting quiz-like scenarios; to force myself think in a different way and which I can maybe have an advantage on unexpected interview questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a book, and not C#-specific, but you could take a look at Project Euler: http://projecteuler.net/

Answer (score 3):

stackoverflow.com, of course :) - just reading the q and a on this site makes me think a different way.

[Learning C# with exercises, questions and puzzles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311205/learning-c-with-exercises-questions-and-puzzles)

Comment: yeah i have found that jsut browsing through stackoverflow has been very enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not specific to C#, [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2):

you can find a lot of solutions in c# to [project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) challenges. This is one resource: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/projecteuler

Also the benchmarks on [The Computer Language 
Benchmarks Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org) have solutions in c# (mono). They encourage people to contribute faster solutions and by looking at them you can learn good performance-tuning tips.

Finally, if you're coming from another programming language and want to compare ways of solving common tasks, sites like [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aC_sharp) or [langref](http://www.langref.org) are precious. They are also good to just learn how to do common things in a new language or as a reference (or indeed as preparation to common interview questions)

Answer (score 0):

A StackExchange site: [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)