# Can you advise me a resource with LINQ/lambda code exercises?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

Can you advise me an a resource with simple C# LINQ/lambda-expressions code exercises?

Desirable but not obligatory: online, free, with answers, step by step, the simplest and fast, to study the syntax but not complicated puzzles or world problems.

I do not think it is duplicated with

- [Learning C# with exercises, questions and puzzles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311205/learning-c-sharp-with-exercises-questions-and-puzzles)

since it was 2+ years ago, so propably outdated, and it did not contain any good reference (looked through all of them).

The best google search result I managed to find is:

- [C# exercises and solutions-C# variables and data types](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-variables-exercises.htm)

though I am not satisfied.

**Update**:
Something similar to [LINQ Quiz](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqquiz.aspx) which is for me the best reference I could find to this moment.

Comment: Best two answers already posted, so I'm going to close this.  Requests for external resources are off-topic here.  I closed the post you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good ressource for LINQ is Jon Skeet's blog "Reimplementing `LINQ` to Objects".
He reimplements the whole LINQ functionality step by step giving excellent insights about the inner workings.

[Reimplementing LINQ to Objects](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a tutorial of such but I've found it very usefull for the linq side of things...

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Saw it and fount them extremely heavy and difficult to follow for very simple things. I would call it as the example of how the samples should not be done. Besides, I asked for exercises not for ready samples